# Woocommerce Delivery based on city and Location

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a food delivery based woo commerce site where I need to deliver products only to two specific cities and selected locations. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is actually replace the checkout / billing fields to your needs. Woocommerce supplies you with a bunch of examples here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/ on how to modify / add / remove those fields.

In your case I would remove the city inputfield and replace it with a custom Select.